# How do I incorporate canned plums into sake

Tags: sake

I have a recipe for making sake, that came with my koji-kin, but I can't find any mention of adding flavoring. I want to be able to add canned plums to my sake.

recipe ingredients

- 4 liters water
- 3.3lbs rice
- .9lbs kome-koji
- .18oz citric acid
- .18oz yeast

Comment: I'm not really a sake expert, but one way might be to add them after primary fermentation and then just let them infuse in the sake for a while before bottling.

Answer (score 1):

Once you've innoculated and are ready for fermentation you can put them in.
You may want to add a Pectic Enzyme as well to break down the complex sugars and help with the clearing.
Depending on the pulpiness of the plums, you may need to rack and strain more.
You should also need only about 0.5 tsp of koji added to 400g of starter rice, which adds up to 0.9lbs just to clarify.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a try. I will mark this as correct if it works, since you did not involve any references.

Comment: No upvotes for this answer @Paul even if you haven't had a chance to test it?